# How to calculate a sum of values if .xml files are pulled in via a collection into an .xsl style sheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, collections

I have a list of .tcx files that I pull into my style sheet using a collection ...

```
<xsl:template name="main">
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('file:///d:/in/?select=*.tcx')"/>
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>
```

Now I have an other template where I process the content of these .xml files

```
<xsl:template match="/garmin:TrainingCenterDatabase">
    <xsl:for-each select="./garmin:Activities/garmin:Activity">
      <xsl:for-each select="./garmin:Lap">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(base-uri(.),'\.')[2]" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@StartTime" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="garmin:TotalTimeSeconds" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="garmin:DistanceMeters" /> m</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="garmin:Calories" /></td>
        <xsl:call-template name="sum">
          <xsl:with-param name="elements-to-sum" select="//garmin:DistanceMeters" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

As you can see I have a sum template (that calls itself recursively to sum all DistanceMeters) as well where I try to calculate a rolling sum of all DistanceMeters but it is not working in a way I expect. I takes all elements in the collection separately and restarts the sum with each new element ...

Is there a way to calculate these rolling sums (or other things like a sequence number that I can use to number the results for example) across the whole collection ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to declare a global param or `<xsl:variable name="coll1" select="collection('file:///d:/in/?select=*.tcx')"/>`, then, where needed, you can easily compute `<xsl:value-of select="sum($coll1//garmin:DistanceMeters)"/>`. You could then also change the `<xsl:apply-templates select="collection('file:///d:/in/?select=*.tcx')"/>` to use the variable `<xsl:apply-templates select="$coll1"/>`.

Comment: Thank you! Just a quick one: if I refer to this collection via the newly introduced variable does this mean that the style-sheet processor will re-scan all the documents again and again?

Comment: If you use a global variable and then reference it in all places where you need to process the collection then in my understanding the processor reads in all files once and works with the sequence of trees it has built once.